# multiple insert query using stored procedure NOT WORKING

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

when i insert single record it is successfully inserted but cannot insert multiple records.I get below error message

> **Error:**   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.  Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: **Error
>   converting data type nvarchar to datetime.**

My Sql Table

```
create table railbkg
(

[type] nvarchar(50),
sr nvarchar(50),
tran_no varchar(50),
pnr varchar(50),
trainno varchar(50),
fromstn varchar(50),
fromstn1 varchar(50),
boardingst nvarchar(50),
tostn varchar(50),
tostn1 varchar(50),
doj datetime,
currentstatus varchar(50),
chartprepared varchar(50),
seatno varchar(50),
status varchar(50),
dob varchar(50),
bookid varchar(50),
mth varchar(50),
basicamt nvarchar(50),
fullname1 nvarchar(50),
fullname nvarchar(50),
pax varchar(50),
class varchar(50),
btc varchar(50),
pgc_waiver nvarchar(50),
c nvarchar(50),
ichg nvarchar(50),
stonichg nvarchar(50),
bist nvarchar(50),
pgc nvarchar(50),
stonpg nvarchar(50),
netcc nvarchar(50),
pnr nvarchar(50),
pgcwamt nvarchar(50),
pgcwamtst nvarchar(50),
camt nvarchar(50),
finalamt nvarchar(50),
cancel nvarchar(50),
refund nvarchar(50),
refamt nvarchar(50),
rcptamt nvarchar(50),
refdate varchar(50),
moj varchar(50),
remarks varchar(50),
temp varchar(50),
asignstatus nvarchar(50),
id int not null,
cc_Id int,
rfid int,
statementid nvarchar(50)

)
```

> My Stored Procedure

```
SP_HELPTEXT SPInsrailbkgCY
CREATE procedure SPInsrailbkgCY          
@type nvarchar(50),          
@sr nvarchar(50),          
@Tran_no varchar(20),          
@pnr varchar(10),          
@trainno varchar(5),          
@fromstn varchar(50),          
@boardingst nvarchar(50),          
@tostn varchar(50),          
@doj datetime,          
@currentstatus varchar(50),          
@seatno varchar(50),          
@status varchar(50),          
@dob datetime,          
@bookid varchar(50),          
@mth varchar(50),          
@basicamt nvarchar(50),          
@Fullname nvarchar(50),          
@pax varchar(50),          
@class varchar(50),          
@btc varchar(50),          
@pgc_waiver nvarchar(50),          
@C nvarchar(50),          
@ichg nvarchar(50),  
--@stonichg nvarchar(50),          
--@bist nvarchar(50),          
@pgc nvarchar(50),          
--@stonpg nvarchar(50),          
--@netcc nvarchar(50),          
@pnr1 nvarchar(50),          
@pgcwamt nvarchar(50),          
@pgcwamtst nvarchar(50),          
--@Camt nvarchar(50),          
--@finalamt nvarchar(50),          
@cancel nvarchar(50),          
@refamt nvarchar(50),          
@rcptamt nvarchar(50),          
@refdate varchar (50),          
@moj varchar(50),          
@remarks varchar(50),          
@temp varchar(50),          
@asignstatus nvarchar(50)         
as          
begin    
declare @ST float    
declare @stonichg as nvarchar(50)       
declare @bist as nvarchar(50)        
declare @pgcamt as nvarchar(50)        
declare @stonpg as nvarchar(50)        
declare @netcc as nvarchar(50)        
declare @Camt as nvarchar(50)         
declare @finalamt as nvarchar(50)        
declare @fcal as nvarchar(50)  
declare @fpgc as nvarchar(50)  
set @st=0.15   
set @fcal= Cast(@basicamt as float)+cast(@ichg as Float)  
 set @fpgc=cast(@pgc as float)  
set @stonichg= round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)          
--set @bist=(@basicamt+@ichg+@stonichg)  
set @bist= @fcal+ round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)   
set @pgcamt= round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))* @fpgc/100,2)          
set @stonpg= round(round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)*0.145,2)        
set @netcc= @fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)+round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)+round(round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)*0.145,2)        
set @camt= (@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)+round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)+round(round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)*0.145,2))*0.03        
set @finalamt= @fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)+round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)+round(round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)*0.145,2)+(@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2)+round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)+round(round((@fcal+round(convert(float,@ichg)*0.145,2))*@fpgc/100,2)*0.145,2))*0.03        
insert into           
railbkg           
(          
[type]  
,sr          
,Tran_no          
,pnr          
,trainno          
,fromstn          
,boardingst          
,tostn          
,doj          
,currentstatus          
,seatno          
,status          
,dob          
,bookid          
,mth          
,basicamt          
,Fullname          
,pax          
,class          
,btc          
,pgc_waiver          
,C          
,ichg          
,stonichg          
,bist          
,pgc          
,stonpg          
,netcc          
,pnr1          
,pgcwamt          
,pgcwamtst          
,Camt          
,finalamt          
,cancel          
,refamt          
,rcptamt          
,refdate          
,moj          
,remarks          
,temp          
,asignstatus          
)          
values           
(          
null          
,null          
,@Tran_no          
,@pnr          
,@trainno          
,@fromstn          
,@boardingst          
,@tostn          
,@doj          
,@currentstatus          
,@seatno          
,@status          
,@dob          
,@bookid          
,null          
,convert(float,@basicamt)          
,@Fullname          
,@pax          
,@class          
,@btc          
,@pgc_waiver          
,@C          
,convert(float,@ichg)          
,@stonichg        
,@bist        
,@pgcamt  
,@stonpg  
,@netcc              
,@pnr          
,0          
,0          
,@camt        
,@finalamt        
,null          
,null          
,null          
,null          
,convert(datetime,@doj)          
,@remarks          
,null          
,0          
)       
end
```

My C# code

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SPInsrailbkgcy");//insert in railbkg if commission is yes
                    comm.Connection = con; 
                    comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sr",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tran_no", lb1.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnr",lb2.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainno",lb3.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fromstn",lb4.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@boardingst",ddlbroadst.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tostn",lb5.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj",lb6.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentstatus",ddlsts.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@seatno",txtstno.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status",lb7.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob",lb8.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookid",dlstprofile.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mth", DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@basicamt",txt1.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fullname",dlst1.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pax",lb10.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class",lb9.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@btc",lb11.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgc_waiver",dlst3.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",dlst4.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ichg",lb12.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgc",dlst5.SelectedItem.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pnr1",lb2.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgcwamt","0");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pgcwamtst","0");
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cancel",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refamt",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rcptamt", DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@refdate",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moj",lb6.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remarks",txt2.Text);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@temp",DBNull.Value);
                    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@asignstatus", "0");
                    con.Open();
                    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),
                                 "alert2", "alert2();", true);
                    con.Close();
                    sendmail(lb2.Text);
```

I Don't Understand what is Wrong with this code

Comment: Well - the error message actually tells you what's wrong. You're trying to put a nvarchar into a datetime, meaning you have data in a format that's not convertable or mapped incorrectly.

Comment: Your `dob` is type varchar but your store proc is datetime.

Comment: @Ibibo `@doj` is `DateTime` in your `SP`, but you are assigning string in your `C#` code

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen but single query is passing without any error,

Comment: Data is different between single query and multiple queries.

Comment: @DheerajPatnaik i Can't Get what you said please come again

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen now its working i converted the data in my cs parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change these lines:

```
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob",lb8.Text);
comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@doj",lb6.Text);
```

to these:

```
comm.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(lb8.Text);
comm.Parameters.Add("@doj", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(lb6.Text);
```

All datetime columns should converted to datetime when receiving value from a textbox, which by default returns string value.

Alternatively, edit your SP with converting dob & doj to datetime in insert query:

```
CREATE procedure SPInsrailbkgCY (
-- simplified for brevity --     
@doj datetime,          
@dob datetime,
-- simplified for brevity --        
as          
begin
-- simplified for brevity --        
insert into railbkg (  
-- simplified for brevity --
,doj   
,dob 
-- simplified for brevity --         
)          
values           
( 
-- simplified for brevity --
,convert(datetime,@doj)    
,convert(datetime,@dob) 
-- simplified for brevity --
)
```

Comment: my cs command run successfully, still do i need to alter my storedprocedure?

Comment: Just choose one: if you don't want alter C# code, alter the SP and vice versa, then make sure datetime value inserted in proper date/time format. Alternatively you can set all datetime textbox to display date format mask, thus user need to obey preset formatting without altering both C# code and SP.